# Splitting an IplImage

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I'm having a variable **char* ImgMem** which contains the image memory of the desired image (three channels / RAW 16) and I would like to split it by three and put each one of them in an IplImage of a single channel: one for R, one for G and one for B.

How is it possible to access the R channel for example from a **char* variable** without being passed by an IPLImage?

I know it's pretty much easier to save the image file and split it, but I have just to deal with memories and not files.

Looking forward to hearing from you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you would like to extract the three channels in three images, namely R, G and B.

For this purpose, look at [cvSplit](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/operations_on_arrays.html#cvSplit)

Comment: thank you.
I will clarify the situation:
I'm having an IPLIMAGE OF 16U,C1 and I want to convert it to 8U,1C and at the end to have 8U,3C to split it into three seperate channels, without saving the image in a file and loading it.